# Fetch refs without downloading objects

Tags: git

I want to check if origin/master differs from my HEAD.

I do **not** want to `git fetch`, as it may be very expensive - I abuse git in a way that makes the cost prohibitively high.

Anything that would allow me to get a list of commits or a top commit from the remote without actually downloading the objects would be fine.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
git ls-remote http://yourproject.git origin/master
```

It will return the last SHA of commit in remote master branch