# Downloading only a file's "differences" using Git & Github?

Tags: python, json, git, github

I'm making a Python program that visualizes Covid vaccination data on a world map using *[Our World In Data's](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations)* vaccination data in .json format. I'd like to introduce a feature where the program downloads the latest .json file from OWID's Github and replaces the old one, provided that there is at least a 24 hour difference between the 'last modified' dates of the two files.

My question is whether I can instead harness Git/Github's power to quickly compare the *contents* of the local file and remote file and *only* download whatever's different between the two, in order to cut down on the size of whatever has to be downloaded. The end goal is using as little bandwidth/time for downloading a fresh version of the file as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this quite cleanly by using Git directly: Keep a local clone of the repository, then run `git pull` to get the latest updates. A command like `git fetch; git status` could tell you beforehand whether you're out of sync or not. Git is optimized for pulling down updates to a file as efficiently as possible.

Comment: `git fetch` will download all updates - it's not any faster than `git pull` assuming you're primary bandwidth limited. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741890/fetch-refs-without-downloading-objects for an example of how to fetch a ref without fetching objects.